# Spring Boot Gradle bootBuildImage task with private repo

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot / Gradle project to use bootBuildImage to build my Docker image, but am hitting a snag. We have limited external network access on our build servers; we use a private nexus repository.

When I try to run the bootBuildImage task, it's attempting to request a file from repo.spring.io:

```
[creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[creator]     unable to contribute spring-cloud-bindings layer
[creator]     unable to get dependency spring-cloud-bindings
[creator]     unable to download https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar
[creator]     unable to request https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar
```

I have `repo.spring.io` added as a repository on our nexus server, but I'm unclear on how to get the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to use it. I tried adding it to my `repositories` block, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

```
repositories {
    // Other repositories...
    //
    
    maven {
        url "<my nexus server>/repository/spring-io-releases/"
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There is a relevant [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/issues/101)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I needed to [configure the download uri of the bellsoft-liberica JDK used inside the Spring Boot build image goal/task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65212231/4964553) to not use github.com - but my own private server instead. It cannot be done with [buildpack environment variable](https://paketo.io/docs/reference/configuration/#environment-variables) alone, but you can [use bindings for that!](https://paketo.io/docs/reference/configuration/#dependency-mappings)

Please note that with the [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization) or [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization) it requires Spring Boot 2.5+ (a `bindings` option has been added in 2.5). If you're on an older Spring Boot release, you need to either upgrade or switch over to [pack CLI](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/).

Bindings can be configured [either through volumes or Kubernetes secrets](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#how-to-use-bindings). I created [a fully comprehensible guide on how to use bindings in order to change a uri used inside a buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212256/4964553) - but I will outline the key steps for switching the spring-cloud-bindings-x.y.z.jar uri:

**1. Create bindings directory**

In order to hand over the binding configuration to `pack` CLI we need to **create a directory first**:

```
mkdir spring-cloud-config && cd spring-cloud-config
```

**2. Create file type, containing the binding key**

Now we need to create a file called `type` inside this directory containing the binding key for [the spring-boot buildpack binding type `dependency-mapping`](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot#type-dependency-mapping):

```
echo "dependency-mapping" >> type
```

**3. Create file named as the sha256, containing the spring-cloud-bindings-x.y.z.jar uri**

Now we should create another **file named exactly according to the `sha256` digest value** of the `[[metadata.dependencies]]` section of the `spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar` inside the [buildpack.toml](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/blob/main/buildpack.toml):

```
[[metadata.dependencies]]
id      = "spring-cloud-bindings"
name    = "Spring Cloud Bindings"
version = "1.7.0"
uri     = "https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar"
sha256  = "e3c18bf1a3c2e52743f9ff2fa46af59e5eee0a7f0683ff562eb35aa866e4a9e9"
stacks  = [ "io.buildpacks.stacks.bionic", "org.cloudfoundry.stacks.cflinuxfs3" ]
```

This file **must contain the uri of your internal nexus incl. the spring-cloud-bindings.jar**:

```
echo "http://<my nexus server>/repository/spring-io-releases/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar" >> e3c18bf1a3c2e52743f9ff2fa46af59e5eee0a7f0683ff562eb35aa866e4a9e9
```

**4. Execute pack CLI with --volume to use the binding**

Finally we can issue our `pack` CLI command. Ensure that [pack CLI is installed on your system](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/):

```
pack build your-application-name-here \
    --path . \
    --volume $(pwd)/spring-cloud-config:/platform/bindings/spring-cloud-config \
    --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

Alternatively, you can use the `bindings` option with Spring Boot 2.5+ Maven or Gradle plugins, see links above.

Now the spring-boot buildpack will download the `spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar` from `http://<my nexus server>/repository/spring-io-releases/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar` instead of `https://repo.spring.io/release`.

Comment: But I was generating the image using the Spring 2.4.2 version until two weeks ago, now that it started giving this error. Do you know why?

Comment: New firewall rules in your companies network?

Answer (score 3):

The `bootBuildImage` Gradle task uses [Paketo](https://paketo.io) Buildpacks to build your OCI container. There are a bunch of buildpacks participating in the creation of the container, one of them is the [Spring Boot Buildpack](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bindings). Among other things, the Spring Boot Buildpack will add Spring Cloud Bindings to the application classpath:

```
 [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 1.7.0: Contributing to layer
 [creator]         Downloading from https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar
 [creator]         Verifying checksum
 [creator]         Copying to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_spring-boot/spring-cloud-bindings
```

This all happens inside the build container and the buildpack is not aware of your Gradle repositories. The dependency URL is defined in the [buildpack itself](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/blob/main/buildpack.toml#L42):

```
[[metadata.dependencies]]
id      = "spring-cloud-bindings"
name    = "Spring Cloud Bindings"
version = "1.7.0"
uri     = "https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.0.jar"
sha256  = "e3c18bf1a3c2e52743f9ff2fa46af59e5eee0a7f0683ff562eb35aa866e4a9e9"
stacks  = [ "io.buildpacks.stacks.bionic", "org.cloudfoundry.stacks.cflinuxfs3" ]
```

Using the environment variable `BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED`, you can disable autoconfiguring Spring Boot environment properties from bindings, but the jar file will be pulled anyway.

```
bootBuildImage {
    environment = ["BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED" : "false"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried setting that environment variable, and as you said, it still attempted to pull and failed my task. I take it that what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED does not work at build time: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error now on spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.1 but in the past it worked:

```
...
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Spring Boot Buildpack 4.2.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Creating slices from layers index
[INFO]     [creator]         dependencies
[INFO]     [creator]         spring-boot-loader
[INFO]     [creator]         snapshot-dependencies
[INFO]     [creator]         application
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_spring-boot/helper/exec.d/spring-cloud-bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 1.7.1: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.1/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.1.jar
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute spring-cloud-bindings layer
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency spring-cloud-bindings
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.1/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.1.jar
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.1/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.1.jar
...
```

Old log:

```
...
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Spring Boot Buildpack 4.2.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Creating slices from layers index
[INFO]     [creator]         dependencies
[INFO]     [creator]         spring-boot-loader
[INFO]     [creator]         snapshot-dependencies
[INFO]     [creator]         application
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 1.7.1: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Web Application Type: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Servlet web application detected
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT.default
[INFO]     [creator]       4 application slices
[INFO]     [creator]       Image labels:
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.title
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.version
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.spring-configuration-metadata.json
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
...
[INFO]     [creator]     *** Images (aafb789b0498):
[INFO]     [creator]           docker.io/library/cpo-process-registry:1.0.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/cpo-process-registry:1.0.0'
```